# Ruby Pony emails ssl issue

Tags: ruby, email, pony

I am having trouble getting pony to work. Right now I am getting an error:

> TypeError: wrong argument (NilClass)! (Expected kind of OpenSSL::SSL:SSLContext)

I am using Pony.rb with smtp and here is the method call so far:

```
class Email
     def send_email
             Pony.mail({
                   :to => 'user@domain.com',
                   :via => :smtp,
                   :via_options => {
                         :address => 'smtp.macpractice.com',
                         :port => '587', 
                         :enable_starttls_auto => true,
                         :user_name => 'user@macpractice.com',
                         :password => 'password',
                         :authentication => :plain,
                         :domain => "localhost.localdomain"
                   }
             })
     end
end
```

I've searched through the docs and the smtp.rb file to figure out what's going on but somehow it's not being passed an SSLContext object and I'm not sure how to do that in Pony.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just figured out the answer. It was to turn off the SSL verification like so:

```
require 'pony'
class Email
    def send_email 
            Pony.mail({
                    :to => 'cole@macpractice.com',
                    :from => 'blaine@macpractice.com',
                    :subject => 'test',
                    :body => "yo dude",
                    :via => :smtp,      
                    :via_options => {
                            :address        => 'smtp.macpractice.com',
                            :port           => '10040',
                            :user_name      => 'blaine',
                            :password       => '',
                            :authentication => :cram_md5,
                            :domain         => "localhost.localdomain",
                            :openssl_verify_mode    => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
                            :enable_starttls_auto   => false

                    }   
            })
    end
end
```

setting the starttls_auto to false and the ssl verify mode to verify none creates an smtp email without the ssl verification.

Comment: Yeah, it's a doozy using SMTP SSL junk.